# Flask TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement

Tags: python, flask

```
@app.route('/login',methods=["GET","POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password'].encode('utf-8')

        cur = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=%s",(email,))
        user = cur.fetchone()
        cur.close()

        if len(user) > 0:
            if bcrypt.hashpw(password, user['password'].encode('utf-8')) == user['password'].encode('utf-8'):
                session['name'] = user['name']
                session['email'] = user['email']
                return render_template("home.html")
        else:
            return "Error password or user not match"
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")
```

this is my login part in flask program. but when I try to log in, this error pops out.

TypeError
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1953, in full_dispatch_request
return self.finalize_request(rv)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1968, in finalize_request
response = self.make_response(rv)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2097, in make_response
raise TypeError(
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.

TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

What does it means? other solutions are said it is because there's no return but I have returns
and even on a same indentation.

HELP ME!

Comment: Do you have `home.html` and `login.html` in a place where Flask can find them?  You are encoding the 'password' field, but you're not encoding the 'user' field.   Is that a bytes value?  Do you need to encode the fields from the SQL query?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add response for each else condition in your code.

check below code :

```
from flask import jsonify

if len(user) > 0:
    if bcrypt.hashpw(password, user['password'].encode('utf-8')) == user['password'].encode('utf-8'):
        session['name'] = user['name']
        session['email'] = user['email']
        return render_template("home.html")
    else:
        return jsonify({"message":"Error password or user not match"})
else:
    return jsonify({"message":"user not available"})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if len(user) > 0:
    if bcrypt.hashpw(password, user['password'].encode('utf-8')) == user['password'].encode('utf-8'):
        session['name'] = user['name']
        session['email'] = user['email']
        return render_template("home.html")
else:
    return "Error password or user not match"
```

You need to return something in case the password does not match. Your if-block will only catch the case where no users are found.